# Python: dealing with None parameters

Tags: python

What is the best practice?
1) have a function be able to take in None?
2) practice to not to send None to a func

is it just personal preference or are there any pros/cons to this?

I have a func

```
def parse_path(path):
    site = None

    site_pattern = re.compile('(fl|ny|wa|tx)')
    match = site_pattern.search(path)
    if match:
        site = match.group(0)

    return site
```

so obviously if i pass in None to parse_path, it will complain.
TypeError: expected string or buffer

so should I always be conscious of what to put in to a func or should a func be flexible so it deals with None?

Comment: Why is it the functions fault if something else passes in the wrong type? `None` is not special here. What if I passed in a list, or a float instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters so there should be a type check within a func?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be. It's the responsibility of the caller to pass in the correct types. If `None` is not a supported type, then you should fix the code calling your function to not pass in `None`.

Comment: @ealeon If someone passes None or a non-string path this function will fail quickly without a check. Treating path=None as a special case would only be necessary if path was an optional parameter.

Comment: as @IanStevens said, ultimately what's important is to **fail fast and explicitly**. As long as your function does that, you should be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using `None` as default sometimes as in:

```
def dosomething(input1, input2=None):

    if not input2:
        input2 = compute_default_input2

    carry_on()
    ....
```

This can be useful in classes that can be used in multiple ways or where certain properties require computationally intense initialisation, so you don't want to do this unless it's requested -- adding None as default makes that possible.
It's also a cheap way to allow users to override an object's properties:

```
def dosomething(self, property=None):

    if not property:
        property = self.property
```

This will use the `self.*` value by default but allow the user to override it.
It's also something of a hack, so as most things in Python should probably used with care.

... other than that: I think `None` as an input should only be dealt with in a function if there's a reasonable use case where `None` is passed to that function, and that very much depends on the environment that it is operating in. If you can reasonably expect everyone to be aware they shouldn't call your function with `None` then the standard error message from Python should be enough to make clear what the problem is.

Comment: a shorter way to write that is `property = property or self.property`

Comment: You might want to test for `property is not None` since `not property` evaluates to `True` for `False` or any empty list or string as well.